# Email alert from process builder value from sender field is not used

Tags: process-builder, email-alert

I'm having issue with process builder and email alert, maybe someone knows fix for this issue.

I'm having process builder set on the opportunity that whenever we change the record or create new one and we meet business criteria, we are sending email alert to related contact of the opportunity.

In the email alert I changed 'From Email Address' to one of our organization wide email address.

So expected behaviour is that email from should be myOwdEmail@mydomain.com, but always when I'm changing or creating a opportunity the sender is my user or the user who triggered process builder and this is not expected behavior.

I tried to send apex email message with sender as our organization wide email address and it's working.

Now the question is,  am i missing something or should I create new case with salesforce support for this issue?

Thanks for all answers

Comment: If process is on opportunity why testing by creating case rather test by updating Opportunity.

Comment: Thanks @Mitesh , i had a typo here ;)

Comment: does the running user (of the PB) belong to a profile with access to the OrgWide email address?